# How to install MinGW 64 bit in Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, windows-7, eclipse-cdt, mingw-w64

I want to work in Eclipse CDT 64 bit and I have installed it in my machine. But after that I came to know that it needs MinGW to work. But I didn't find any website from where I can know how to setup MinGW64 bit. Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because you could find the answer using Google, see user1394710's answer below.

Comment: This isn't a specific programming problem. How to find and install software is off-topic.

Comment: See also "Downloading and installing MinGW-w64": http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Downloading%20and%20installing%20MinGW-w64

Answer (score 0):

First hit on Google for 'mingw 64 bit eclipse': http://pinyotae.blogspot.no/2010/05/eclipse-mingw-x64.html